# Modular Arithmetics and Big Powers

Tags: javascript

Is there a way i can calculate this in javascript.
I need to solve such type of expressions for encrypting/decrypting.

```js
const x = 1999 ** 5678 % 567;
console.log(x);
```

Comment: If you want to use encryption/decryption, don't write your own algorithms. Use a proven library instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1999 ** 5678` is a big number which has about 19,000 digits. It's too large to fit in a `number`.

But you can use BigInts instead:

```js
console.log((1999n ** 5678n % 567n).toString());
```

(I use `toString` above only so that it works in the Stack Snippet interface, which doesn't support BigInts yet.)

Comment: I think my result is right. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281999+%5E+5678%29+mod+567

Comment: x = (((1999n ** 5678n % 567n).toString())*1)
console.log(x);
console.log(typeof(x));